# How to remove a sentence that occurs after 'MORE:' in the given string?

Tags: python-3.x

**For the news articles which I have scraped, I am trying to omit the sentence that occurs after 'MORE:', as it is a backlink and has nothing to do with the article.**

> The prime minister announced a new COVID Alert System to track the coronavirus R number -- the rate at which the virus reproduces -- that will determine how the country phases out of lockdown. The R number is now between 0.5 and 0.9 in the U.K., he said. If the data supports it, by June at the earliest some schools could open, and by July, pending â€œfurther scientific advice,â€ the government hope that areas of the hospitality industry may be able to reopen.

> MORE: What it's like inside the Oxford trial leading the race for coronavirus vaccine

> If we as a nation begin to fulfil the conditions I have set out, then in the next few weeks and months we may be able to go further.....

So for the above example, I want the python program to delete the line which follows 'MORE:' till a new line i.e. '\n' is detected which means that the article follows on from there.

PS - I know that regular expressions would be most likely used in such a case but I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: Could you provide any code that you've tried so far in order to get the article contents? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using the regex [positive lookahead](https://www.regextutorial.org/positive-and-negative-lookahead-assertions.php) method.

So your pattern will be

```
pattern = r'(?=MORE:)(.*)'
```

Pattern Explanation:

- `(?=MORE:)`: Will match any group after the expression `MORE:`, without including it in the result
- `(.*)`: Will group 0 or any character that are not line breaks

Your final code in python will be

```
import re
pattern = r'(?=MORE:)(.*)'
target_string ='''
The prime minister announced a new COVID Alert System to track the coronavirus R number -- the rate at which the virus reproduces -- that will determine how the country phases out of lockdown. The R number is now between 0.5 and 0.9 in the U.K., he said. If the data supports it, by June at the earliest some schools could open, and by July, pending â€œfurther scientific advice,â€ the government hope that areas of the hospitality industry may be able to reopen.

MORE: What it's like inside the Oxford trial leading the race for coronavirus vaccine

If we as a nation begin to fulfil the conditions I have set out, then in the next few weeks and months we may be able to go further.....'''
without_more = re.sub(r'(?=MORE:)(.*)','',target_string)
print(without_more)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution:

```
without_more=target_string[:target_string.index('MORE')]
print(str(without_more))
```